# What does class_addProtocol actually do in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addProtocol) for `class_addProtocol` is very basic and doesn't really explain how to use it.

My interpretation is that when I want to add a protocol to a class at runtime I should call `class_addMethod` to add each method from the protocol and then call `class_addProtocol`. What I don't really understand is *if* and *why* I need to call `class_addProtocol`. Surely by adding all the protocol methods the class already conforms to the protocol, so what does `class_addProtocol` actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows for the selector `-conformsToProtocol:` to work. In some situations (where you may have multiple delegates, who may need to respond to certain things but not others), it's useful to know if the object responds to the protocol, instead of just the single method you are requesting.

Most of the time this isn't an issue, as most of the time `-respondsToSelector:` is sufficient, but it's a good tool to have handy.

Note that you should almost never use `class_conformsToProtocol` over `-conformsToProtocol`, as that doesn't check superclasses, and can cause issues.

Comment: I always assumed `conformsToProtocol` was equivalent to the logical AND of `respondsToSelector` for all required methods in the protocol, but apparently it just returns whether a class *declares* that it adopts a protocol regardless of whether it actually does or not. Thanks for helping me to understand this.

Comment: @jhabbott: Consider a protocol that defines no required methods. If a class is declared to conform to it, how could the "logical AND" approach ever determine if a class was conformant?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan A zero-argument AND is `true`. However there are other reasons for this behavior: If two classes have the same ivars, they still aren't the same, unlike in duck typing. The principle is the same here, too.